# google drive api returns 403 forbidden when downloading file content

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I am trying to download content of a previous revision of a file using the google drive api for Ruby [Google::Apis::DriveV3::DriveService#get_revision](https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-api-client/latest/Google/Apis/DriveV3/DriveService.html#get_revision-instance_method):

```
Tempfile.create('file_revision-', encoding: 'ASCII-8BIT') do |temp_file|
  drive_api_service.get_revision(file_id, revision_id, download_dest: temp_file)
  # work with the content
end
```

I keep getting `Google::Apis::ClientError` with status code 403, reason phrase "Forbidden". The scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` is enabled and the error occurs only when I am trying to download the content of the revision. If I run the code without the parameter `download_dest`, the request succeeds without any problems. I am also able to fetch any meta data or revision, export files, upload files etc., the problem only occurs when I try to fetch the content, either by `get_file` or `get_revision`.

Has anyone encountered this issue?
Is there an additional permissions that specifically needs to be added to allow content downloading?

I have also looked at other questions on stack overflow and I have checked all possible configuration for google drive api I could find and everything seems to be enabled.

Comment: Hi there @JanHric! I tried to reproduce the error with your code, but I couldn't do it. To better study your scenario, could you please share a minimal example that replicates the issue without any modification? To prevent any faulty file, did you check if this error appears on other files? Also, since this is a 403 error, do you totally own the file? Did you implement a credential handling code?

Comment: Thank you for your interest @Jacques, I managed to find the problem with a colleague of mine - google api simply does not allow content downloading for native google drive files.

Comment: I saw your new comment and answer. It's true that you should use [`Files.export()`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export) to download Workspace files. [Here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#download_a_document) is an example of how to approach that method to download PDF files. I understand that your original scenario required a byte stream, does the former approach count as a valid workaround for your needs? If not, please share why you need a binary input in your code.

Comment: I need to restore the previous revision of a file, but there is not an api for that, so I wanted to download the previous content and upload it again to restore the previous revision manually and export would not work for that, as I would get the content in a different format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, Google drive api does not support content downloading for native google drive files (google docs, sheets etc.), so you cant download content (current or of an old revision), you can only export it to a different mime type.